# ¿Cómo crear reportes personalizados en Django?

Tags: python, django

¿Cómo puedo crear reportes personalizados en *Django* que se puedan filtrar por fecha, y varios campos de un modelo?

Adicionalmente, quisiera poder exportarlos en formato de `Excel`, `Word`, o `PDF`.

**¿Hay alguna forma de hacer también esto?**

Comment: Utilice esta librería para los pdf.http://python.org.ar/wiki/Recetario/FacturaPyFpdf

Comment: Creo que la pregunta necesita edición para clarificar su comprensión. No queda claro a que le llama **reporte**, esto puede ser un _queryset_. Tiene que clarificar a que se refiere con **_faltar por fecha_**. Sin esas aclaraciones, estamos adivinando.

Comment: @toledano si, falta trabajo en esa pregunta, sin embargo, entendí que lo que desea es generar reportes para descargarlos como Excel, Word, PDF, etc.

Comment: David, ¿mi respuesta solucionó tu pregunta?

Answer (score 14):

Tu pregunta es bastante amplia, sin embargo trataré de explicarla de la forma mas general que me sea posible.

Una forma en la que puedes generar reportes en las vistas de Django es mediante el objeto [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) y usando las cabeceras necesarias. Por ejemplo, para generar un [PDF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/) o un [CSV](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-csv/) (observa la diferencia en sus `content_type`):

```
# PDF
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="reporte.pdf"' 

# CSV
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="reporte.csv"'
```

Eso es en general, lo que debes hacer para exportar en el formato que deseas. Para usar la información de tus modelos solo tendrías que iterar y presentar la información de acuerdo a lo que necesites y finalmente retornar el objeto `HttpResponse` para su descarga, de esta forma y tomando como ejemplo un archivo CSV tu vista podría mas o menos verse asi:

```
import csv
from django.http import HttpResponse

def exportar_csv(request):
    # Crear el objeto HttpResponse con sus cabeceras
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="reporte.csv"'

    # Se usa el response como un "archivo" destino
    writer = csv.writer(response)

    # Obtener los objetos que deseas exportar e iterar
    objetos = MiModelo.objects.all()
    for objeto in objetos:
        row = [
            objeto.campo_1,
            objeto.campo_2
            objeto.campo_3
        ]
        writer.writerow(row)
    return response
```

En este caso hemos usado la librería `csv` que ya viene dentro de las librerías de Python por defecto. Para Excel, Word, y PDF deberías buscar que módulos se acercan a lo que estás tratando de hacer ya que no existen librerías "pre-instaladas" y puede ser muy subjetivo.

Puedes intentar con las siguientes:

- Para PDF: [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/), [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2)
- Para Excel: [XslxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/), [pyExcelerator](https://readthedocs.org/projects/pyexcelerator/)
- Para Word: [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- Para formatos tabulares: [Tablib](https://tablib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (contribución de @Jeasoft)

### Actualización:

Para filtrar los resultados por fecha y otros campos de tu modelo, lo que puedes hacer es crear un formulario para tu reporte usando un [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) y filtrar esos resultados en tu vista. En un archivo (normalmente se usa `forms.py`):

```
# forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from miapp.models import MiModelo


class MiModeloForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MiModelo
        fields = ['fecha', 'campo_x', 'campo_y']
```

En tu [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#the-template):

```
# mitemplate.html

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

La [vista](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#the-view) actualizada con el formulario:

```
import csv
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from miapp.forms import MiModeloForm # El formulario que creaste

def exportar_csv(request):
    form = MiModeloForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MiModeloForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Obtener los objetos que deseas exportar e iterar
            # filtrado por los campos del formulario
            objetos = MiModelo.objects.filter(
                fecha=form.cleaned_data.get('fecha'),
                campo_x=form.cleaned_data.get('campo_x'),
                campo_y=form.cleaned_data.get('campo_y')
            )

            # Crear el objeto HttpResponse con sus cabeceras
            response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="reporte.csv"'

            # Se usa el response como un "archivo" destino
            writer = csv.writer(response)

            for objeto in objetos:
                row = [
                    objeto.campo_1,
                    objeto.campo_2
                    objeto.campo_3
                ]
                writer.writerow(row)
            return response
    return render(request, 'mitemplate.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Además de todo lo descrito por @césar-bustíos, para los Excels tambien puedes usar una librería llamada Tablib, la he usado anteriormente para hacer reportes personalizados en diversos formatos tabulares. https://tablib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @Jeasoft gracias! Lo agrego a la respuesta

Comment: django-import-exports usa tablib.

Comment: Lo que no se ve en la respuesta, es lo que pide en el primer párrafo de la pregunta:

_que se puedan filtrar por fecha, y varios campos de un modelo_.

Parece que se está respondiendo a otra pregunta.

Comment: @toledano no se a qué te refieres, se está respondiendo a la consulta sobre la exportación. Falta la parte que dices pero recien se ha aclarado luego de la ultima edición

Answer (score 3):

Usa [`django-import-export`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), tiene soporte para bastantes formatos, no incluye PDF, tiene Mixins para acciones por medio de botones en la interfaz, y una buena documentación.

Comment: Hola, tienes los enlaces de referencia a la librería y/o documentación?

Comment: Este es: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Perfecto, ya agregué el enlace

Comment: No olvides puntiar mi respuesta.

Comment: Claro, lo hará mañana, ya me quede sin votos hoy :P

Comment: Amigo, mi punto :D